# How to Build Status Update UI

Tags: android

I am trying to create a UI like this (circled in blue): 
[image]

Is this the product of an edit text? What view would get me the closest to achieving this layout?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely, that is several views in a container (e.g., a `ConstraintLayout`). I see two `ImageView` widgets, a `Spinner`, a `Button`, and what I am guessing is an `EditText` with a hint (for the "share a status update" stuff).

Comment: I see, and how would I rap the edit text text on a new line kind of like twitter? Is it just a matter of padding and how the edit text is formatted?

Comment: `EditText` word-wraps, just as `TextView` does. You set the width, height, maximum lines, maximum line length, etc., and it handles the rest.